# what's the difference between revolute joint and wheel joint

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, cocos2d-x

for the joint of revolute and joint of wheel,they look quite similar,seems we can use 
revolute joint do that wheel joint can do?i searched the box2d manual,it is very simple for this section,i also checked the source code of box2d,it just say something like wheel joint is designed for vehicle suspensions.does anybody know what's the difference between them,more specific speaking,what exactly the wheel joint it is?if you can give me a sample of wheel joint(c++ version),i will be very grateful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The revolute joint can be thought of as a hinge, a pin, or an axle. An anchor point is defined on each body, and the bodies will be moved so that these two points are always in the same place, and the relative rotation of the bodies is not restricted.

Revolute joints can be given limits so that the bodies can rotate only to a certain point. They can also be given a motor so that the bodies will try to rotate at a given speed, with a given torque. Common uses for revolute joints include:

- wheels or rollers
- chains or swingbridges (using multiple revolute joints)
- rag-doll joints
- rotating doors, catapults, levers

Joints added after v2.1.2:

Wheel - the line joint, renamed

And the line joint can be described as
a combination of revolute and prismatic joints, useful for modelling vehicle suspension

Follow this link on joints. It may make clear the difference between these joints in a better manner.

http://blog.allanbishop.com/box2d-2-1a-tutorial-part-2-joints/

Answer (score 0):

A revolute joint (also called pin joint or hinge joint) is a one-degree-of-freedom kinematic pair used in mechanisms.[1] Revolute joints provide single-axis rotation function used in many places such as door hinges, folding mechanisms, and other uni-axial rotation devices.